# strange behavior of a stage class when use spring

Tags: java, spring

Good day. I have a strange behavior of my JavaFX application. I inject controller into loader with use spring but halfway through it becomes NULL. I have a class stage like this:

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Service
public class Stage extends Application {
    private Controller controller;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Stage.class);
    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    public Stage(Controller controller){
        logger.debug("constructor");
        logger.debug(controller.toString());
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    public Stage() {
    }

    @Override
    public void start(javafx.stage.Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        logger.debug("start(primarystage)");
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        URL location = getClass().getResource("/company/sample.fxml");
        loader.setLocation(location);
        logger.debug(loader.toString());
        logger.debug(controller.toString());
        loader.setController(controller);
        Parent parent = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(parent, 300, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public void start(){
        logger.debug("start()");
        launch();
    }
}
```

This is a log:

```
10:26:42.887 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'controller'
10:26:43.035 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'stage' <--------------
10:26:43.035 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'stage' <-------------------
10:26:43.040 [main] DEBUG company.ui.Stage - constructor <------ constructor have been executed
10:26:43.040 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'controller' <--- spring given him a 'controller' bean
10:26:43.053 [main] DEBUG company.ui.Stage - company.Controller@130161f7 <---- it is not null
10:26:43.054 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'stage' to allow for resolving potential circular references 
10:26:43.069 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'stage'
10:26:43.074 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'stage' 
10:26:43.074 [main] DEBUG company.ui.Stage - start() <-- start() have been executed 
10:26:43.323 [JavaFX Application Thread] DEBUG company.ui.Stage - start(primarystage) <------ start(primary stage) have been executed
Exception in Application start method
10:26:43.332 [JavaFX Application Thread] DEBUG company.ui.Stage - javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader@420ac8a9 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:875)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(LauncherImpl.java:157)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$1/793138072.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException <----- controller is null!!!!!
    at company.ui.Stage.start(Stage.java:42)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(LauncherImpl.java:821)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$50/1910484864.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(PlatformImpl.java:323)
```

I can not understand how it happened.

Comment: it is an experiment. without this behavior is the same

Comment: You never created a `Stage` object, and hence `controller` is null?

Comment: You have 2 instances. one created by spring, which has its dependencies injected and one instance created by JavaFX which doesn't have anything injected. Your start method is called on the non spring managed instance.

Comment: @M.Deinum, how can i fix this?

Comment: Don't let your application be a spring bean. Create the application context in your application then autowire the application. For a Spring Boot based sample take a look at [this](https://github.com/thomasdarimont/spring-labs/tree/master/spring-boot-javafx)